# Carregar ficheiro em java

Tags: java, eclipse

Preciso fazer o upload de um arquivo .xlsx que está em um diretório para minha ferramenta.

Qual API ou implementação posso utilizar para realizar o upload?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a bliblioteca [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/download.html) para isso

Abaixo segue um exemplo de como você pode carregar um arquivo .xlsx com a biblioteca Apache POI, posteriormente você pode salvar a mesma em um diretório que achar mais conveniente.

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ExcelReader {
    public static final String XLSX_FILE_PATH = "./arquivo-excel.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        //Criando um Workbook de Uma Arquivo Excel (.xlsx ou .xls)
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(XLSX_FILE_PATH));

        //Visualizando Todas as Sheets presentes na planilha
        for(Sheet sheet: workbook) {
            System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
        }


        // Visualizando os valores das células da primeira aba da planilha
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        for (Row row: sheet) {
            for(Cell cell: row) {
                String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

#### Terminologia do Apache POI

- Workbook: Uma pasta de trabalho é a representação de alto nível de uma planilha.
- Sheet: Representa uma aba da planilha. Uma pasta de trabalho pode conter muitas abas.
- Row: Como o nome sugere, representa uma linha na planilha.
- Cell: uma célula representa um elemento na coluna da planilha.

Comment: Obrigado pela alternativa, usei e funcionou